# how to apply custom style on StringValidator toolTip

Tags: css, apache-flex, actionscript

I am using stringValidator component in flex.

```
<mx:StringValidator id="toValidator" source="{To}" property="text" triggerEvent="click"  >
</mx:StringValidator>
```

It is working properly but problem is that I have applied borderSkin on ToolTip in my default styleSheet which change the appearance of the message by the validator.

```
mx|ToolTip
{
   borderSkin: Embed(source="assets/componentImages/TabBar-tab_selectedUpSkin.png");
}
```

Now I want that this borderSkin should not be applied on my stringValidator. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The error tooltip has it's own stylename, errorTip.  You just need to specify it to now include the borderSkin.

```
.errorTip { borderSkin: none}
```

Should do it.

Comment: Thanks but "errorTip" is a class selector. How can we apply this style.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  It's the styleName applied to all error tooltips.  Just add this to your main CSS file or in the Main.mxml in the <fx:Style> tags and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

take a look to [Flex Style Explorer](http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex3StyleExplorer.html)
you can build your own css file which can manage all of your components easy way